# I deleted an important application on my rooted phone

Tags: rooting, unbricking

After rooting my phone (HTC Bolt), I foolishly deleted some bloatware applications without backing them up. One of them was TouchPal, a preinstalled keyboard app. I didn't think this would be much of a problem because I already had it disabled in settings and was using a separate keyboard app for other purposes.

However, when I restart my phone, it always asks me to type my pin and "decrypt" the phone. I'm not sure why it does this (previous cell phone didn't), but apparently (this is only a theory) it uses this keyboard application, so I can't actually type my PIN in to decrypt my phone.

I could be completely wrong, and I might have accidentally deleted some other important file from my phone, but either way, I don't know how to fix my phone right now.

I did a bit of research and found out I was supposed to flash a ROM onto my device. However, I don't think I can even connect my device to my computer because normally I would have to enable USB debugging and file transfers.

Update: I booted up my phone in recovery mode (TWRP) and it was able to connect to my PC.

Comment: Based on your update, all you need to do now is flash your keyboard app again. You can create a custom flash package and have the keyboard app within it. I think you can reuse any of the flashing packages that write to your system apps directory.

Comment: @blueren There's no need of a flashable .zip if OP has TWRP: they just need to place the .apk of the keyboard in the correct directory inside the `/system` partition, and adjust permissions and ownership accordingly to the other apps.

Comment: Where would the correct directory for the apk be? Also how would I adjust permissions for the apk?